# Auto Delete Stack on Instance Termination

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am currently working with EC2 instances and have made a Java CLI tool to quickly launch/kill instances for our developers. One of the options is to set a lease time, so that the instance terminates after a certain amount of hours. For spot instances this works great, terminates the instance, the request, and deletes all volumes associated with that instance.

However, for on demand instances, the lease time only affects instance termination and does not delete the stack that it was on.

Is there some way to automate this through AWS? I don't want to write a script to manually check or even monitor, it would be great if this could be automated through AWS itself. I have looked and have not found anything. Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: I do not think it is possible without monitoring/scripting. There is no native support for this in AWS. Deleting a stack deletes far more resources than an instance. So it is not wise to auto delete a CF stack.

Comment: When you say "delete the stack it was on", are you saying that the instance was launched as part of an AWS CloudFormation stack, and you would like to delete the stack? Are you sure that you have nothing else in the stack that is required? If so, you could make an API call to delete the stack, which would terminate the instance. You could run a script on the instance itself that requests its own termination.